# Blocbuilder not updating when list in map changes

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, freezed

I'm trying to trigger an update when a `list` in my `map` changes. Type is `Map<String, List<int>>`. Basically one of the integers is changing in the list but not triggering the blocbuilder. Although when I print the state the value is updated. I'm using freezed. From what I understand freezed only provides deep copies for nested @freezed objects but not for Iterables. I've seen a few solutions for this kind of problem. For example create a new Map with `Map.from` and emit that map. But that doesn't trigger a rebuild. Any suggestions!

My `freezed` state is

```
onst factory RiskAttitudeState.loaded({
    required int customerId,
    required RiskAttitudeQuestionsInfo riskAttitude,
    required Map<String, List<int>> answerIds,
    @Default(FormzStatus.pure) FormzStatus status,
    int? finalRisk,
  }) = RiskAttitudeLoaded;
```

And I'm updating an integer in the list type `List<int>` in the map `answerIds`

Here is the `bloc`
Future _mapAnswerToState(

```
      String id, List<int> answerIds, Emitter<RiskAttitudeState> emit) async {

    await state.maybeMap(
      loaded: (RiskAttitudeLoaded loaded) async {
        if (loaded.answerIds.containsKey(id)) {
          loaded.answerIds.update(
            id,
            (_) => answerIds,
            ifAbsent: () {
              add(RiskAttitudeEvent.error(Exception('unknown Question ID: $id')));
              return answerIds;
            },
          );
        }

        emit(loaded.copyWith(answerIds: loaded.answerIds));
      },
      orElse: () async {},
    );
  }
```

For contest if I pass an empty map like this `emit(loaded.copyWith(answerIds:{}));`

the builder gets triggered.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a small code with cubit and [Equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable)  and it worked. the key note is that you should override props method and add answerIds and other fields if exists to props and all fields must be final.

also notice to use `Map<String, List<int>>.from` to fill the map.

so the state class looks like this:

```
class UcHandleState extends Equatable {
  final Map<String, List<int>> answerIds;
  const UcHandleState({
    required this.answerIds,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [
        answerIds,
      ];

  UcHandleState copyWith({
    Map<String, List<int>>? answerIds,
  }) {
    return UcHandleState(
      answerIds: answerIds != null
          ? Map<String, List<int>>.from(answerIds)
          : this.answerIds,
    );
  }
}
```

and a simple cubit class for managing events is like below. in `valueChanged` I'm just passing `List<int>`.

```
class TestCubit extends Cubit<TestState> {
  TestCubit() : super(const TestState(answerIds: {'1': [1, 1]}));

  void valueChanged(List<int> newValues ) {
    Map<String, List<int>> test = Map<String, List<int>>.from(state.answerIds);
    test['1'] = newValues;
    emit(state.copyWith(
      answerIds: test,
    ));
  }
}
```

so in UI I call `valueChanged()` method of cubit:

```
 cubit.valueChanged(newValues:[ Random().nextInt(50), Random().nextInt(70)]);
```

and the blocBuilder gets triggered:

```
   return BlocBuilder<UcHandleCubit, UcHandleState>(
        buildWhen: (prev, cur) =>
        prev.answerIds!= cur.answerIds,
        builder: (context, state) {
          print(state.answerIds.values);
         ....
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunality i came accross this problem too. if your algorithm requires change one item of list maybe you can remove this item from your list and then change its properties. after that if you add the item to the list, builder will be triggered..